# Git - how to deal with same repository but different protocol (http and ssh)

Tags: git, http, ssh

At my work there is a restriction about SSH connexion. You can only access if you in the company network, otherwise you have to deal with HTTP and systematic credentials.

So when I work at home I can't push through SSH. Well I added a remote called 'http' referring to the same repository but through HTTP protocol.

So sometimes at home, when I push/fetch or some, git status shots I've got some commits forward origin/branch but not really true it's just that I push thanks to HTTP protocol and the SSH (origin) can't be used at home.

How can I deal ?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I *recommend* this idea, but feel free to *try* it, as it will probably work.  I have, however, not tested this case (and I suspect some poorly-written shell scripts may have issues with unusal namespace setups, although with any luck, all of Git's own internals just work here).

#### Background

The general idea behind a *remote* is that it is a short name for a longer URL.  The URLs in question here are `ssh://...` and `http://...` (or `https://...`, which would probably be better).

As an important convenience, each remote also provides a set of *remote-tracking branches*.  Most commonly we only have one remote, named `origin`, so all of our remote-tracking branches are named `origin/master`, `origin/develop`, and so on.  This hides from us the fact that there is an entire [name space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Namespace) (Computer Science / Informatics term) for these remote-tracking branches.  (Namespace is sometimes hyphenated, or sometimes written as two words or just one word: they all mean the same thing.)

You added a second remote, `http`, so now you have *two* name spaces, containing two remote-tracking branches, `origin/master` and `http/master` for instance.  This would be no big deal, except that the two (apparently) different remotes, `origin` and `http`, are really *the same system*.

Hence, what we might like here is to collapse the two name spaces back into a single namespace.  Let's use `origin` since that's the original and probably the one you use more often (though ultimately it does not really matter).  If we could just convince Git to update `origin/master` instead of `http/master` even when we're fetching and/or pushing from the remote named `http`, Git would update the correct remote-tracking branch.

As it turns out, **we can do exactly that** using the `fetch` configuration lines associated with each remote.

#### Configuring Git

Open your `.git/config` file with an editor that won't Unicode-ize the file, or do all of these configuration items with `git config` if you prefer.  (Run `git config --edit` to have Git fire up your regular editor on it.)  Look at the two existing `[remote]` sections and you will see:

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = ssh://...
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*

[remote "http"]
    url = http://...
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/http/*
```

These two `fetch` lines control the mapping from remote-name to remote-trackig branch name.  If you replace the `http` with `origin` in `refs/remotes/http/*` in the `fetch` line for remote "http", Git will begin using the `refs/remotes/origin` namespace.

To do this with `git config` rather than your editor, simply run:

```
$ git config remote.http.fetch '+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*'
```

You will then probably want to delete all the old `http` names:

```
$ git branch -r -d http/master
```

Also, make sure your local branches track `origin/*` instead of `http/*`.  Use `git branch -vv` to view the tracking branch for each local branch.  (The tracking information is stored in that same `.git/config` file—it should now be obvious how to change it in your editor—but it can be updated with `git branch --set-upstream-to` if you prefer.)  You can fix this up any time, before or after deleting the remote-tracking branches.